# Given a mime-type get the corresponding file extension

Tags: filenames, curl, mime-types

I want to download a file using `curl` to a temporary directory with the appropriate extension.

Currently I do something like this:

```
tmp="$(mktemp -t 'curl')"
curl -o "$tmp" http://example.com/generate_image.php?id=44
file -b --mime-type "$tmp"
```

This will print the mime-type of the downloaded file, but how do I map these to extensions?

As you can see I can't just extract the "extension" of the url as that would give `.php` instead of `.png`.

I know there isn't a one-to-one map between mime-types and file extensions but it should handle normal file extensions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike windows, unix generally has no concept of `file extensions`. However you can use the `/etc/mime.types` file to provide those translations:

```
image/jpeg: jpg
image/gif: gif
image/png: png
image/x-portable-pixmap: ppm
image/tiff: tif
```

and then match by extension:

```
$ ext=$(grep "$(file -b --mime-type file.png)" /etc/mime.types | awk '{print $2}')

$ echo $ext
png
```

Comment: I don't have that file, using OS X.

Comment: Actually I think `/etc/apache2/mime.types` is the same.

Comment: There is a good chance of it (it's how apache serves the mime type in the headers). There is also this answer on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735659/list-of-all-mimetypes-on-the-planet-mapped-to-file-extensions

Comment: Be aware, that in some English "slangs" there are differences in writing some colors. I just recognized that `file` wrote `image/x-portable-greymap`, but in `mime.types` i found it as `image/x-portable-graymap` (grey vs. gray).

Answer (score 0):

Bash Script that takes one parameter - a filename, and attempts to rename it based on its mime-type using the file command and the system mime.types file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the location of your mime-types file here.  On some OS X installations,
# you may find such a file at /etc/apache2/mime.types; On some linux distros, 
# it can be found at /etc/mime.types
MIMETYPE_FILE="/etc/apache2/mime.types"

THIS_SCRIPT=`basename "$0"`
TARGET_FILE="$1"
TARGET_FILE_BASE=$(basename "$TARGET_FILE")
TARGET_FILE_EXTENSION="${TARGET_FILE_BASE##*.}"
if [[ "$TARGET_FILE_BASE" == "$TARGET_FILE_EXTENSION" ]]; then
    # This fixes the case where the target file has no extension
    TARGET_FILE_EXTENSION=''
fi
TARGET_FILE_NAME="${TARGET_FILE_BASE%.*}"


if [ ! -f "$MIMETYPE_FILE" ]; then
    echo Could not find the mime.types file.  Please set the MIMETYPE_FILE variable in this script.
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$TARGET_FILE" == "" ]; then
    echo "No file name given. Usage: ${THIS_SCRIPT} <filename>"
    exit 2
fi

if [ ! -f "$TARGET_FILE" ]; then
    echo "Could not find specified file, $TARGET_FILE"
    exit 3
fi

MIME=`file -b --mime-type $TARGET_FILE`
if [[ "${MIME}" == "" ]]; then
    echo ${THIS_SCRIPT} $TARGET_FILE - Could not find MIME-type.
    exit 4
fi

EXT=$(grep "${MIME}" "${MIMETYPE_FILE}" | sed '/^#/ d' | grep -m 1 "${MIME}" | awk '{print $2}')

if [[ "$EXT" == "" ]]; then
    echo ${THIS_SCRIPT} ${TARGET_FILE} - Could not find extension for MIME-Type ${MIME}
    exit 5
fi


if [ "${TARGET_FILE_EXTENSION}" == "${EXT}" ]; then
    echo ${TARGET_FILE} already has extension appropriate for MIME-Type ${MIME}
    exit 0
fi

echo Renaming "${TARGET_FILE}" to "${TARGET_FILE}.${EXT}"
mv "${TARGET_FILE}" "${TARGET_FILE}.${EXT}"
```